# Floating Action Button could not be instantiated / Error inflating

Tags: xml, android-studio, gradle, floating-action-button

I've been tearing my hair out; this was working just fine ( well.. almost, wasn't floating right) and then it suddenly stopped shortly after I added `android:backgroundTint="@color/fab"` as the minimum SDK is 19.

To try and fix it I have:

- Updated Android Studio / SDK
- Invalidate Caches / Restart
- Rebuilt Project
- Confirmed `targetSdkVersion 23`
- Confirmed `compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'`
- Confirmed `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'`
- Confirmed `<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">`

It's coming up to 5am so sorry if this is glaringly obvious but I don't know what else to try. The XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/com.whereintheworld.com"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:id="@+id/tracking_task_list"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:src="@drawable/fab_ic_add"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/fab"
            app:layout_anchor="@id/tracking_task_list"
            app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21+` added support for tinting widgets on devices running pre `android 5.1 (API Level 21)`. To make use of it make sure you extend or set the **AppCompat Theme** and use `app:backgroundTint` instead of `android:backgroundTint`.

Example:

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton 
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    android:src="@drawable/icon"
    app:backgroundTint="@color/accent"
    app:borderWidth="0dp" />
```